# How do I run GtkInspector?

Tags: 14.10, gtk3

Hello guys I tried to run [GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector)
but I failed tried to:

- Edit dconf files but there is no /org/gtk/settings/debug path
- Running with GTK_DEBUG=interactive python3 my_script.py

But no luck either.What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The embedded GtkInspector is available since GTK 3.14 while Ubuntu 14.10 has version 3.12. So you'll have to wait for Ubuntu 15.04 to use this feature.

You might want to try GtkParasite instead, which GtkInspector is based on. I tried it some months ago, but couldn't get it to work with Python3. This might have changed in the meantime though.

Comment: Is it possible to update 3.12 to 3.14 using repositories ? I tired GtkParasite recently same problem

Comment: You can most likely use jhbuild to build GTK and all its dependencies: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Jhbuild